# Создание элемента со спецсимволом js

Tags: javascript

подскажите, создаю необходимо создать через js элемент с `&times;`(×). У меня получается только через

```
divTask.insertAdjacentHTML(
  'beforeend',
  '<a href="#" class="task__remove">&times;</a>'
)
```

можно ли в начале создать через createElement и затем через свойство указать наполнение? или спецсимволы так нельзя передавать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так

```js
const divTask = document.getElementById('divTask');
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.classList.add('task__remove');
a.href = '#';
a.innerHTML = '&times;'
divTask.appendChild(a);
```

```html
<div id="divTask"></div>
```